# How To Know record history by query

Tags: soql

Anyone knows the query how to track the history of a particular opportunity record , what changes made by the user by SOQL

Comment: Do you have field history tracking enabled on fields for the `Opportunity` object?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use relationship queries to relate the history with the record. Like:

```
SELECT OldValue, NewValue, Parent.Id, Parent.name, Parent.customfield__c
FROM foo__history
```

Please find here the [official docs about this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_hist.htm)

Comment: i am using this query Select Id,Field, NewValue, OldValue,OpportunityId from OpportunityFieldHistory where OpportunityId = '0060k00000Asl4HAAR' and  Field='Name' where i am enabling a custom field in opportunity with set track history but i am unable to query with that new custom field.

Comment: Also if i am using same query with only id then by default i am getting results for stage field but i want result based on custom field which i already enabled set track history setting

Comment: Do you get any error when you try to query that query field? I recommend you using https://workbench.developerforce.com/ to play around with queries easily.